# pgfplots: annotating some line segment outside the grid on the right or upper borders

Tags: pgfplots, intersections, tikzmark

I have the following plot for which I would rather prefer to display the marks of the 3 line segments outside the grid:

. the 1 and 3 should be to the right of the right border, close to the intersection of the corresponding grey lines with the vertical rightmost border of the grid.

. the 2 should be on top of the upper border close to the intersection of the corresponding grey line with the horizontal upper border of the grid.

I would eventually prefer a solution that avoids adding something in the preamble.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\begin{scope}
\begin{axis}[axis equal image=true,xlabel={x},
ylabel={y},
title={sv=12},
xtick distance=2,
ytick distance=2,
minor tick num=1,
grid=both,grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!20},
xmin=-1,xmax=4,
ymin=-1,ymax=4]
\addplot[green!20,only marks]
    coordinates {(0, 0)(0, 1)(0, 2)(0, 3)(1, 0)(2, 0)(3, 0)};
\addplot[green!50,only marks]
    coordinates {(1, 1)(1, 2)(2, 1)};
\addplot[green!20]
    coordinates {(0, 0)(3, 0)(0, 3)(0, 0)(0, 0)};
\draw[fill=green,opacity=0.1] (axis cs:-1,1.6666666666666667) -- (axis cs:4,3.3333333333333335) -- (axis cs:4,10) -- (axis cs:-1,10) -- cycle;
\addplot[black!20,thick]
    coordinates { (-1, 1.6666666666666667) (4, 3.3333333333333335)};
\node[below left,circle,draw=black!20,fill=black!10] () at (axis cs:4,3.3333333333333335) {\scriptsize 1};
\addplot[black!20,thick]
    coordinates {(1.6666666666666667, -1) (3.3333333333333335, 4)};
\node[below left,circle,draw=black!20,fill=black!10] () at (axis cs:3.3333333333333335,4) {\scriptsize 2};
\draw[fill=green,opacity=0.1] (axis cs:-1,4.333333333333333) -- (axis cs:4,-0.6666666666666666) -- (axis cs:4,13) -- (axis cs:-1,13) -- cycle;
\addplot[black!20,thick]
    coordinates {(-1, 4.333333333333333)(4, -0.6666666666666666)};
\node[below left,circle,draw=black!20,fill=black!10] () at (axis cs:4,-0.6666666666666666) {\scriptsize 3};
\end{axis}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: plot corresponding to the code]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to use `extra descriptions`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\begin{scope}
\begin{axis}[axis equal image=true,xlabel={x},
ylabel={y},
title={sv=12},
xtick distance=2,
ytick distance=2,
minor tick num=1,
grid=both,grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!20},
xmin=-1,xmax=4,
ymin=-1,ymax=4,
extra description/.code={
\coordinate (tr) at (1.01,1.01);
\node[anchor=west,circle,fill=gray!20] (description1) at (c1-|tr) {$1$};
\node[anchor=south,circle,fill=gray!20] (description2) at (c2|-tr) {$2$};
\node[anchor=west,circle,fill=gray!20] (description3) at (c3-|tr) {$3$};
}]
\addplot[green!20,only marks]
    coordinates {(0, 0)(0, 1)(0, 2)(0, 3)(1, 0)(2, 0)(3, 0)};
\addplot[green!50,only marks]
    coordinates {(1, 1)(1, 2)(2, 1)};
\addplot[green!20]
    coordinates {(0, 0)(3, 0)(0, 3)(0, 0)(0, 0)};
\draw[fill=green,opacity=0.1] (axis cs:-1,1.6666666666666667) -- (axis cs:4,3.3333333333333335) -- (axis cs:4,10) -- (axis cs:-1,10) -- cycle;
\addplot[black!20,thick]
    coordinates { (-1, 1.6666666666666667) (4, 3.3333333333333335)};
%\node[below left,circle,draw=black!20,fill=black!10] () at (axis cs:4,3.3333333333333335) {\scriptsize 1};
\coordinate (c1) at (axis cs:4,3.3333333333333335);
\addplot[black!20,thick]
    coordinates {(1.6666666666666667, -1) (3.3333333333333335, 4)};
%\node[below left,circle,draw=black!20,fill=black!10] () at (axis cs:3.3333333333333335,4) {\scriptsize 2};
\coordinate (c2) at (axis cs:3.3333333333333335,4);
\draw[fill=green,opacity=0.1] (axis cs:-1,4.333333333333333) -- (axis cs:4,-0.6666666666666666) -- (axis cs:4,13) -- (axis cs:-1,13) -- cycle;
\addplot[black!20,thick]
    coordinates {(-1, 4.333333333333333)(4, -0.6666666666666666)};
%\node[below left,circle,draw=black!20,fill=black!10] () at (axis cs:4,-0.6666666666666666) {\scriptsize 3};
\coordinate (c3) at (axis cs:4,-0.6666666666666666);
\end{axis}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But I would like a solution where the value of the coordinates where to put the label is computed by tikz from the information it has from the line.

Comment: @NicolasBeldiceanu: you can use `axis cs`, e.g.  `... at (axis cs:4.1,3.3333333333333335) ...` for pint 1 (note: `4.1` instead of `4` to get some distance from the axis).

Comment: @NicolasBeldiceanu Better now? I just replaced your nodes by coordinates that are being used to place the description nodes, which are, unlike the nodes you placed, not subject to clipping. You could turn off the clipping but this could have other side effects such I would like to argue that `extra description` is the way to go, after all this is what (I believe) it is made for.

Comment: This looks fine. And yes I do not want to turn off the clipping since this may have some bad effect.

Comment: Yes, this afternoon (I am working on that with a colleague and some unexpected question may pop up this afternoon).

Comment: In fact, since the TikZ I show is produced by a program, the information provided in extra description is not available before we print the different line-segments. So the question is: would it be possible to somehow put the extra description stuff in the last part of the drawing ? If not we will have to modify the flow of the program which produce the TikZ code.

Comment: You are right, you just put c1,c2,c3 in the preamble and the actual values are passed after. What is meaning/logic behind the point (c1-|tr) ?

Comment: @NicolasBeldiceanu `(c1-|tr)` means a coordinate at the vertical position of `(c1)` and the horizontal position of `(tr)`.